# Can I start a web app upon opening a google spreadsheet via the onOpen() function?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-visualization

I would like to create a function that brings up a web app upon opening a spreadsheet. Say for example that I had a spreadsheet with sales data for march, when I open the sheet the web app associated with that data would pop up. Is this possible?

I am thinking maybe I have to nest a doGet() function within an onOpen() function so I am going to try that as a starting point.

Comment: Additionally, I would like to be able to do this for mobile phones as well via the google sheets app if possible.

Comment: There is a way to do this.  It's a multi-step process.  The `onOpen()` function will need to open a sidebar or dialog box.  Then the sidebar or dialog box will need to automatically run some JavaScript, and the JavaScript will run a line to put a URL into the browsers address bar.  Then you can automatically close the sidebar or dialog box if you wish.  `doGet()` only works from a GET request that is detected as an "event" from the browser.  Even though you can probably run `doGet()` by calling it, it's not going to cause the browser to do anything in that situation.

Comment: See this:  [Link to Stack Overflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28163063/2946873)