# Auto close in Google apps script web app form

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, web-applications

How can I auto close an apps script web app form after a user hits the submit button?

I tried the `window.top.close()` but it doesn't work.

I saw solution from other post and tried it. It works only for form inside email but NOT on web app form submit.

[Google apps script web app form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GD86d.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Closing window after running a Google Script web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28161670/closing-window-after-running-a-google-script-web-app)

Comment: Not a duplicate! That's a different form of species... I tried that solution and it didn't cause its different case. My question is all about form submit NOT ON EMAIL.

Comment: Hi did you find a solution?